# Odoo v12 when model changed without the UI event

Tags: orm, odoo-12

I want to know what is the orm model function to call if my model changed without the UI event ?

I'd like to use **@api.onchange('state')** to execute a method. But it does not work because **@api.onchange()** only works if the UI change value. What is the function to call if backend/background changed without the UI event ??

Thanks

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/odoo-v12-when-model-changed-without-the-ui-event-159621

Comment: You can manually call that method in your code.

Comment: More infos please ??. @api.??

Comment: e.g @api.model_is_backendorbackground_changed